# Form creation issue in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mozilla

I'm working on a project in MVC.NET 5. In this project I have a table which has some checkboxes in it. I want to send these checkboxes value to the server and I don't have a form element. But I create a form element with jQuery. Here is the form creation code:

```
$("#setNewRoles").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();        
        var checkbox = $(".checkbox:checked");
        var form = $("<form />").attr({ "action": "/Admin/Account/AddnewRolesForUser", "method": "post" });
        alert(form);
        for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
            if ($(checkbox[i]).attr("disabled") != "disabled") {               
                $(form).append("<input type='checkbox' name='rolesValue[]' value='" + $(checkbox[i]).val() + "' checked />");
            }
        }
        $(form).submit();
    });
```

This code works correctly in Chrome but it doesn't work on Mozilla. What is the matter with the code?

Comment: I suggest you should try with `wrap()` and `unwrap()` jQuery methods for temporary form submit. Example : `$('input:checkbox').wrap('<form/>');`

Comment: nothing changed . wrap didn't work in Chrome too.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtrp9svf/1/). Check this.

Comment: Thank u, I find Solution . I put it as an answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by some tests,

We can Replace above code with this code :

```
$("#setNewRoles").click(function (evt) {       
        evt.preventDefault();        
        var checkbox = $(".checkbox:checked");
        var form = $("<form />").attr({ "action": "/Admin/Account/AddnewRolesForUser", "method": "post", "id": "setRolesForUserForm", "style": "visibility: hidden;" });        
        for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
            if ($(checkbox[i]).attr("disabled") != "disabled") {               
                $(form).append("<input type='checkbox' name='rolesValue[]' value='" + $(checkbox[i]).val() + "' checked />");
            }
        }
        $('body').append(form);
        $('#setRolesForUserForm').submit();
    });
```